# How to prevent buffer overflow

Tags: c

I am being passed an array from a C program that does not include the size of the array; that is, it just passes a pointer to the array. The array is a generic type `<Item>`. How can I determine the end of the array in order to detect a buffer overflow?

I tried iterating through the array until I received something that wasn't an `<Item>`. That worked most of the time but sometimes the nonsense at the end Would be of type `<Item>`. I am using C and calling a function from an external class I had no deal in developing. `<Item>` is a struct with multiple references to other arrays (sort of like a linked list).

EDIT:
The api stated that the array was intended to be a read-only version. The problem is I cannot read it if I do not know the size. It doesn't appear there is a sentinel value. There is a random comment stating that if the size is needed use sizeOf (array)/sizeOf (Item) which doesn't work. It was developed by a team that no longer works here. The problem is other code already relies on this C code and I cannot change it without fear of ruining other code.

Comment: If all you have is a pointer, then you can't find the "end" of the memory it point to. You need to refactor the code so the size is provided by the caller. That's the only way.

Comment: Where does C++ come into play?

Comment: That is the strangest API, that can never work. Can you show us the exact type definition of the array (maybe some home-brew version?). Is there any documentation of this library and how it is intended to be used? Is it developed in-house and can you verify with the developers?

Comment: Where does the **C** come into play when you've got `<Item>`

Comment: @Some programmer dude Not quite the *only* way. Another way would be providing a sentinel value in the passed array.

Comment: You either need to be passed the size of the array or your array needs to contain a sentinel value as element (see answers below).

Comment: @nathanvda It's a strange API, nevertheless, I've seen this in the wild. Obviously, such APIs need to be killed on sight, but that doesn't stop the instance that have successfully evaded all quality-oriented programmers from causing harm...

Comment: Please don't spam with unrelatd language tags.

Comment: I apologize I placed a c++ tag by mistake. I was trying to edit it out but somebody beat me to it. Give me a bit. I'm trying to find the API in this mess. I will post it in an edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to determine the end of an array based on just a pointer to an element of that array.

> I tried iterating through the array until I received something that wasn't an `<Item>`

It's also not possible to determine whether particular memory location contains an object of particular type - or whether it contains any object. Even if you could, how would you determine if the object that you find is really part of the array and not just a separate `<Item>` object that happens to be there?

---

A possible solution is to use a sentinel value to represent the end of an array. For example, you could define the interface such that `<Item>.member == 0`  if and only if that is the last element of the array. This is similar to how null-terminated strings work.

Comment: Or you could require the caller to supply you with an element count. Or with an end iterator. Point is, the interface must be expanded.

Comment: @cmaster Indeed. Although, the question was about how to detect the end when the size is not passed, but only a pointer instead.

Comment: Just wanted to say that it's probably worth making your last paragraph more clear about the necessary consequence: There is no way to know the length with this API, so you must expand the API. All hell may break loose if you don't. You have been warned."

Comment: I will need to request a team to rewrite the code. Thanks for the answer. I appreciate the validation.

Answer (score 3):

If all you have is a pointer and no size or known "end-of-array" marker (sentinel) in the data, then you have an impossible situation. There is *no way* in that case to determine the size/end of the passed array.